# Deploy to render.com fail

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to deploy an express server written in Typescript to render.com, the process keeps failing because of some errors like this -

src/utils/validatePermissions.ts(2,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../errors/Unauthorized' or its corresponding type declarations .

When I work locally everything goes smoothly. I have in the project inside the src folder an errors folder in which I have custom errors files, in every file in the project where I use one of these errors I get an error during , does anyone know how to help?

here is errors/Unauthorized and  utils/validatePermissions-

```
export class UnauthorizedError extends Error {
  status: number;

  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    this.name = 'UnauthorizedError';
    this.status = 401;

    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, UnauthorizedError.prototype);
  }
}

import { Types } from 'mongoose';
import { UnauthorizedError } from '../errors/Unauthorized';

export const validatePermissions = (
  ownerUser: Types.ObjectId,
  currentUser: string
) => {
  if (ownerUser.toString() === currentUser) return;
  throw new UnauthorizedError(
    'You do not have permission to perform this action'
  );
};
```

Thanks for any help!

I tried to delete this folder and then add it from the beginning, I tried to delete node_modules, expected to resolve the issue and succeed to deploy but it keeps fails no matter what I do.